# How to implement only required method in interface using Java

Tags: java

I have an interface with three methods and I have implemented the two methods in my subclass.

During this, I faced a compile time error.

How do I handle this situation?

Snippet One:

```
package com.college.problems;

public interface MethodDefination {

    void methodOne();
    void methodTwo();
    void methodThree();        
}
```

Snippet Two:

```
package com.college.problems;

public class MethodImplementation implements MethodDefination {          

    @Override
    public void methodTwo() {
        System.out.println("Tested");
    }

    @Override
    public void methodThree() {

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("MethodDefination.methodThree()");
    }

    public static void main (String args[]){
        MethodImplementation m = new MethodImplementation();
        m.methodTwo();
    }
}
```

Note: I don't want to implement all the methods that are required by the interface.

Comment: Essentially, you can't that's the point of the interfaces.  You either need to provide a "empty" implementation or make the implementing class `abstract`, but then you can't instantiate it :P

Comment: You don't want to implement or don't want to support? if u don't want to support throw `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` from those methods

Comment: @NitinDandriyal That the way for doing it, like some built in java datastructures

Comment: Create more then one interface, which extends from each other, this way, you can choice where you wan to "jump" in

Comment: One more way is to define adapter classes (Adapter is a pattern that provides default (often empty) implementation of interface or abstract class) heavily used in swings

Answer (score 6):

If you don't implement all the methods of the `interface`, your class must be `abstract`, in which case you can't create an instance of it.

In **Java 8**, if your `interface` contains `default` implementations for some methods, you don't have to implement them in classes that implement the interface.
But of course, you can override them into sub-classes, if you need that.

Answer (score 3):

No you cant do that use implementing class as abstact instead but you cant instantiatiate the class then.By using interface you are having full abstraction so you have to implement all the methods in it.If you want to use only two methods use abstract class.

You can also change interface to abstract class like

```
 abstract class MethodDefination {

    void methodOne() {};
    abstract void methodTwo();
    abstract void methodThree();

 }
 public class MethodImplementation extends MethodDefination {



    public void methodTwo() {
        System.out.println("Tested");
    }


    public void methodThree() {

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("MethodDefination.methodThree()");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MethodImplementation m = new MethodImplementation();
        m.methodTwo();
    }
 }
```

Output

```
Tested
```

Comment: if they're in an abstract class, and you extend that in a concrete class, you still have to provide an implementation for all of them.

Comment: @Stultuske check my edited code I was saying to make interface to abstract class

Comment: for in this scenario i don't want to implement the methodThree()

Comment: @Ramakrishnan yet it is implemented.

Comment: @singhakash: every abstract method of an abstract class has to be implemented for each non-abstract class that extends it. exact same issue.

Comment: @Stultuske so thats what my point is I use `methodOne() {}` so you dont need to provide body in subclass (removing the error of OP)

Comment: then you are providing an implementation, which is not what is supposed to be done.

Comment: @Stultuske thats why I have given both the cases subclass as abstract and interface as abstact since it is not achievable with interface OP has to sacrifice something to achieve that.

Comment: @singhakash: the problem with putting methodOne(){} in an abstract class is, that it will always compile, whether or not the subclass provides a proper implementation or not.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is simple: don't implement the interface.

If you do implement it, either your class must be abstract, or you must implement all the methods defined in the interface (unless you are already inheriting an implementation).

Why not implementing it like you did methodThree? Or do something like this:

```
public void methodOne(){}
```

Though it is better to throw an Exception, just to notify the using developer he shouldn't do this, and alert the user that something unexpected happened;

Comment: The recommended exception is UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: Agreed. Which is why I asked why not implementing it the way he did methodThree, since that throws an UnsupportedOperationException.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is No.

But if you want to define some functionality then you could implement some methods and define that class as `abstract`. In this way your functionality is defined.

But for this type of code, you will have to create a concrete class and use the existing method written in abstract class and also override unimplemented methods in concrete class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are `implementing` an `interface`, then you must have to override all the methods in it.

However to achieve your goal, you can use `abstract` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an Abstract class that implements this interface with empty methods, or some other default behavior. Now, don't implement interface, just extend your Abstract class (Your extending class still will confirm to the interface the abstract class implements), and override only the methods you need. It is a common practice in java libraries, for example in swing, where you have for instance MouseListener which is a interface, and MouseAdapter, which is a Abstract class. You can use Abstract class if don't need to handle all of the mouse events, but only some of them, so you don't need to implement it all, and your code is smaller and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Default method concept here. Default methods are introduced in JAVA8.

Which method you don't want to implement keep that method as a default method in your interface and implement remaining two methods in the subclass of that interface.

For More information about default methods check the below link

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

Otherwise change your interface to abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

You can chose from three options:
1. Create an abstract class and implement only those methods that you need.
2. Use prototype method i.e public void methodThree() {}
3. If you have significant number of classes that use this interface then you can go for Adapter design pattern and give default/prototype implementation in adapter class. you can read about adapter design pattern at [enter link description here](http://www.journaldev.com/1487/adapter-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

Implement your interface to a class(B) , that will override all your method of interface(A)

And then use your B class to mainClass by extending it and use your required method:

```
interface A{
    abstract void method1();
    abstract void method2();
    abstract void method3();
}

class B implements A{
    public void method1(){
        
    }
     public void method2(){
        
    }
     public void method3(){
        
    }
}
class MainClass extends B{
    public void method1(){
        System.out.println("hehe");
    }
}
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    C obj = new C();
    obj.method1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read solid principle in java Once you do, you will get your answer.
Using the interface segregation Principle to overcome this problem
You have to split the interface into smaller ones. Make separate interfaces for each method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!