# Not implementing a method from an abstract class (and making it not accessible)

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class, default, visibility

I was trying to create some Java classes with some shared methods among them and with some other methods only available for some of those classes (and each of those methods are supposed to be different).

I did some research and I found that I could either develop an `Interface` with `default` methods or an `abstract` class with `abstract` methods.

My issue is that I would like to make those unimplemented methods not available when using the class. I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30475351/6671476) but I think it is a little bit of overkill to throw an `Exception` for the unimplemented methods. Below is the code I was testing.

**AvailableMethods:**

```
public abstract class AvailableMethods {

    // This is the shared method
    void methodOne(){
        System.out.println("Common method implementation");
    }

    // This should always be implemented and have always different logic
    abstract int methodTwo();

    /* This should be only implemented in some cases and when not 
       implemented it should not be visible while using the class */
    abstract String methodThree();

}
```

**ClassA:**

```
public class ClassA extends AvailableMethods {

    @Override
    public int methodTwo() {
        return 123;
    }

    @Override
    public String methodThree() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

**ClassB:**

```
public class ClassB extends AvailableMethods {
    @Override
    public int methodTwo() {
        return 456;
    }

    // I was trying to get rid of this implementation without defining a default value
    @Override
    public String methodThree() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        ClassB b = new ClassB();

        b.methodOne();
        b.methodTwo();
    }

}
```

Basically what I wanted to achieve was when typing `b.` in my IDE the `methodThree` not being suggested/available.

I don't know if it is that possible. I have also tried with `default` interface methods without success. I am not sure if it is a hierarchic issue (maybe I should implement different classes and extend ones from others limiting the visibility of the methods) but it seems a little odd to me not existing a way of doing this without too much classes/interfaces.

Comment: Not possible. You probably don't want to use inheritance here, but maybe composition

Comment: Consider that an `abstract` method that *shouldn't* be implemented by a subclass doesn't really make a lot of sense. Put it into a separate interface and implement the interface as required.

Comment: @JonK so what you are saying is that I should create an `Interface` for each combination of methods I can have? Suppose alongside `methodThree` I have also `methodFour` and `methodFive`, all optional. Considering that some classes will only implement `methodThree`, others both `methodThree` and `methodFour`, and so on (with all the combinations) that wouldn't be a lot of boilerplate for nothing? Or did I get it wrong?

Comment: By the way, if someone could provide me input for a possible reason for the -1 vote I would appreciate it in order to ask a better question next time :)

Comment: It might be a bit of boilerplate but it isn't for nothing - it gives you the object structure you're looking for. That said, it sounds like you'd benefit from taking a hard look at the structure you're looking to implement to see if there's another way you could model it that would make more sense.

Comment: A possible solution could be to create an `interface` for every method, then a class can implement all the interfaces it desires. You could still keep your abstract class implementing the interface with `methodOne` and then let every class inherit from that base class

Comment: @Lino that's what I was thinking, thanks for your help ;)

Comment: @JonK I will, thank you

Comment: I will second @Lino option, it is a much cleaner approach.  And if you are using jdk-8 then you can even provide a default implementation in the interface itsself.

Comment: The interface approach is certainly the best and cleanest. If you absoluteley had to, you could also formally implement all abstract methods, but throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` for the ones that you do not really have. That behaviour should be documented in the abstract class.

Comment: @Lino is right, Interface segregation is a great way to go for this. There's a great article on [stackify](https://stackify.com/interface-segregation-principle/) if you want to know more.

Comment: @RCaetano If you donot want to change the existing interface or abstract class, you can make the methods default and enforce the restriction using annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, I put up a small sample for you.

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(){
        ClassA a =  new ClassA();
        a.methodOne();
        a.methodTwo();
        a.methodThree();

        ClassB b =  new ClassB();
        b.methodOne();
        b.methodTwo();

    }
}

interface One {
    default void methodOne(){
        System.out.println("Common method implementation");
    }
}
abstract class Two implements One {
    public abstract void methodTwo();
}

interface Three {
    void methodThree();
}

class ClassA extends Two implements  Three{
    public void methodTwo() {}
    @Override
    public void methodThree() {}
}

class ClassB extends Two {
    public void methodTwo() {}
}
```